# Prove linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working on linear transformation trying to answer :

> Let $E$ and $F$ be two vector spaces on $\mathbb{K}$ and $L:E \rightarrow F$ a function. The graph of $L$ is $\mathbb{G}(L)=\{(x,y) \ \in \ E \times F\mid\ y=L(x)\}$.
>
> Prove $L$ is a linear transformation if and only if $\mathbb{G}(L)$ is a sub vector space of$ E \times F$.

I've tried using the definition of a linear transformation and sub vector space but do not manage to proove the result.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know about the vector subspace test?

Comment: Hint: show the closure property of a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $G(L)$ is a linear subspace in $E\times F$.

You need to prove that
$$L(\alpha x )= \alpha L(x)\\
L(u+v)=L(u)+L(v).$$
Take any two points  $(x_i,y_i)\in E\times F$ belonging to $G(L)$; in other words, $L(x_i)=y_i$, $i=1,2$. By definition of linear subspace you have $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\in G(L)$. Therefore, by the definition of graph you get $L(x_1+x_2)=y_1+y_2=L(x_1)+L(x_2)$. Similarly, for any constant $\alpha$ you get $(\alpha x_1,\alpha y_1)\in G(L)$ and therefore $L(\alpha x_1)=\alpha y_1 = \alpha L(x_1)$. These two results allow us to conclude that $L$ is linear.

The proof in the other direction is done likewise.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
(u,L(u))+(v,L(v))= (u+v,L(u)+L(v))=(u+v,L(u+v))
$$
The first identity come from the canonical definition of a product vector space, the second from the definition of $\mathbb{G}(L)$ and from being a vector space.

The same you have for:
$$
c(u,L(u))=(cu,cL(u))=(cu,L(cu))
$$

From this you can see that $L$ is linear. The inverse is easy.

Comment: Actually, this line of reasoning shows that if $L$ is linear, then the graph is a subspace, not the other way around. So "you can see that $L$ linear" is wrong.

Comment: @Thomas: **If** The graph is a subspace **than** the element $(u+v,L(u)+L(v))$ is in the graph and it has the form $(x,L(x))$, so it is $(u+v,L(u+v))$ and this implies that $L(u)+L(v)=L(u+v)$

Comment: It's true, but that wasn't the argument you made.

Comment: Fundamentally, you have to state the property of the graph: If $(x,y),(x,z)\in G(L)$ then $y=z$. Then you know that $(cu,cL(u)),(cu,L(cu))\in G(L)$ so $cL(u)=L(cu)$.

Comment: Thomas. I given a hint. So the detailed argument  was left open on purpose. I suppose that it can be suggested by the formula. :)

Comment: But a hint is something that ought to be true. You should indicate with "show" if what you are asserting is something that needs to be proved. Read your "hint" the other way, and it is exactly as my first comment says - it is a proof that if $L$ is linear then $G(L)$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: I cannot grasp the point, probably because my English is very poor. In My mind my answer was exactly an hint to what I write in my comment. But I Have to improve my English!!